# Which live screencasting software supports a Mac Power PC?

Tags: mac, screencasts, powerpc

I have a Mac Power PC and I have been wanting to do a live screencast of a this thing I do, but there doesn't seem to be a single widget out there that would help me out.

It is not just a matter of grabbing the screen, I have Snapz Pro X and it will work, but I want to share it with a bunch of people in real-time, which I haven't found yet for the Power PC architecture.

Answer (score 0):

In real-time?  Not that I know of.

The only thing close that I can think of is that VineServer (formerly OSXVNC) has the option Preferences > Sharing > Server > "Always allow multiple VNC connections", in combination with "Disable remote control of keyboard and mouse" that might give you multiple concurrent viewers over VNC in real-time.

...But that's only screen sharing it's not recording (which it sounds like you need) :-(

...Unless one of the realtime viewers runs something like Snapz Pro x and records?  ...still that's only video, you would have to record audio separately and edit together `<yetch/>`.